# What week does baby start listening?

Tags: hearing

I am 4 months pregnant and wondering in which week of the pregnancy does my baby start to listen ?

Comment: There is lots of evidence that talking to your infant a lot, narrating your day, etc. long before your baby can understand the words really helps language development. Why not begin early, if only to train yourself for later?

Answer (score 2):

Supposedly a fetus is capable of hearing, depending on the source, as early as at around 16th week of pregnancy [[1]](http://www.whattoexpect.com/pregnancy/your-baby/week-16/ear.aspx) or 20th week[[2]](http://www.babycenter.com/0_developmental-milestones-hearing_6509.bc), or 24th week [[3]](http://www.pregnancyandbaby.com/pregnancy/articles/945349/fetal-development-what-does-baby-really-hear-in-utero). Apparently, people are not sure:) But what is important is that the baby really does listen quite a long time before it is born.